# What method have ability show android version of device

Tags: android, sdk, android-version

Who's know how to get android version in code for example i need something like this

```
text.setText(somemethod.getAndroidVersion().toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you are looking for?

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

You can also try this `Build.VERSION.RELEASE;`